# In Eclipse Plug-in, how to launch a web url using system broswer?

Tags: java, eclipse, browser

I am working on an eclipse plugin development. It needs to launch system broswer and open a link. In Swing/SWT, I can do it like this:

```
java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI("http://www.google.com");
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
```

And in fact, this code also works in Eclipse plug-in. But I am wondering if eclipse has its own way to do this? Using AWT in eclipse seems some kind of weird...

Comment: Does using Color(s), Font(s), Dimension(s), Image(s) etc. with SWT seem weird?  Those are all AWT.  I would put it down to some unfortunate choices by Sun and get on with your life/development.

Comment: In SWT, there are org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color, org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font and org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image. I've no specific reasons but I think it is not a good idea to mix up two different UI system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Equivalent of `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri)` is this `Program.launch("http://www.google.com");`

```
import org.eclipse.swt.program.Program;

public class del 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Program.launch("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

The javadoc says:

> Launches the operating system
>   executable associated with the file or
>   URL (http:// or https://). If the file
>   is an executable then the executable
>   is launched. Note that a Display must
>   already exist to guarantee that this
>   method returns an appropriate result.

Comment: how to get org.eclipse.swt.program.Program?? is there any jar avaiable?

Comment: How the hell this class eluded me for so long!?!? Great one! Thanks!