# Open local html page - java

Tags: java

In one of my java console application, I am dynamically creating html page. Now I want to open it using default web browser. So can you guys please help me out to solve it.

Comment: You want your application to launch the browser, displaying your dynamically created HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swing** `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);`

**SWT** `Program.launch(uri);`

Taken from [In Eclipse Plug-in, how to launch a web url using system broswer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534571/in-eclipse-plug-in-how-to-launch-a-web-url-using-system-broswer/4534728#4534728)

Assuming you have a file to open.

Answer (score 1):

You should read [Runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) it allows you to execute a launch of a program (your default browser for instance.

Answer (score 0):

With Java, your website is dynamic, so you need a server to run your web application. The most common one is Apache Tomcat. You should read about Tomcat if you plan to program websites with Java.

Comment: tomcat would be heavy for his task I'm sure that more lightweight servlet container exists for such task such as winstone http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winstone_Servlet_Container or Jetty http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty